# OpenCV Drawing Bounding Box CenterPoint

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to draw a Dot in Bounding Box that will represent the Center Point of that box.
I have computed the center Point but it is only outputted in CMD and I wont this Point to be visible on a image.

I am working with OpenCV2.4.3 on Visual Studio 2010 C++

```
 for(int i= 0; i < boundRect.size(); i++ )
       {
            //BoundingBox Area
            boundingBoxArea.clear();
            boundingBoxArea.push_back(Point2f(boundRect[i].x, boundRect[i].y));
            boundingBoxArea.push_back(Point2f(boundRect[i].x + boundRect[i].width, boundRect[i].y));
            boundingBoxArea.push_back(Point2f(boundRect[i].x + boundRect[i].width, boundRect[i].y + boundRect[i].height));
            boundingBoxArea.push_back(Point2f(boundRect[i].x, boundRect[i].y + boundRect[i].height));

            double area0 = contourArea(boundingBoxArea);

            cout << "area of bounding box no." << i << " = " << area0 << endl;

            //Bounding Box Centroid
            area0 = (boundRect[i].x + boundRect[i].width)/2, (boundRect[i].y + boundRect[i].height)/2;

            cout<<"Rectangle " <<i<< " Centroid possition is at: " "=" <<area0<<endl;
            cout<<""<<endl;
            cout<<""<<endl;
     }
```

The above is the code that i use well only a small part but a part that is responsible for calculations on Bounding Boxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oh, you already calculated the area, and now you're trying to assing the center(Point) to that ? oh, no.  replace your last lines with:

```
//Bounding Box Centroid
Point center = Point((boundRect[i].x + boundRect[i].width)/2, (boundRect[i].y + boundRect[i].height)/2);

// print it:
cout<<"Rectangle " <<i<< " Centroid position is at: " << center.x << " " << center.y << endl;
```

also, your boundingBoxArea is wrong. take the original boundingRect[i] instead (for calculating the area), please!

Comment: Well spotted this actually now allowed me to use Circle()function to draw my Dot/Center Point

Comment: But but the Center point gets drawn outside the bounding box so there is more problems with this code :D

Comment: well spotted, again ;) the boundingBoxArea is wrong, use the initial boundRect instead

Comment: the boundingBoxArea is wrong[Rect is (x,y,w,h) not (x,y,x+w,y+h)], use the initial boundRect instead

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative**

Using Moments, your code may also look as follow (java, not tested):

```
..
MatOfPoint contour = new MatOfPoint();
Rect box = boundRect[i];
//Points order doesn't matter
contour.fromArray(new Point[]{new Point(box.x, box.y), //top-left
                  new Point(box.x + box.width, box.y), // top-right
                  new Point(box.x,  box.y + box.height)}); //bottom-left
                  new Point(box.x + box.width, box.y + box.height), //bottom right
int Cx = (int)Math.round(M.get_m10()/M.get_m00());
int Cy = (int)Math.round(M.get_m01()/M.get_m00());
..
double area0 = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
..
```

**Background**

**Image moments** help you to calculate some features like center of mass of the object, area of the object etc. Check out the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) page on Image Moments

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('star.jpg',0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)

cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
print M
```

Centroid is given by the relations, **Cx=M10/M00** and **Cy=M01/M00**.

```
Cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
Cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
```

See OpenCV tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html#gsc.tab=0).

Answer (score 0):

OK guys I managed to solve my own problem on my own makes me feel proud hehe :D

I released that the equation it self was wrong, because i was dividing both x & width and y & with which was wrong the offset given by x & y was wrong. So i changed the code around so that i only divide width/2 and height/2

The final ingredient for the solution was to use the cv::circle(); function which i used to draw the center point.

HOPE THIS MIGHT HELP SOME PEOPLE SOME DAY :D

thx to @berak

Final Result:

[image]